# Show the mapping $z^2$ is a homeomorphism?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $f(z) = z^2$, and $\mathbb{C}$ has the standard Euclidean metric, is $f$ a homeomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Clearly $f$ is continuous.
2. According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)
   it is open.
3. It is surjective too (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).

but $f$ is not injective.

Generally for $n>1$, $z^n$ is not a homeomorphism just because it is not injective.